# How to find an anchor with a button in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium

The following HTML code is for clicking a button

```
<a href="#">
    <button id="listbtn" class="btn btn-info" type="button" name="listbtn">Create</button>
</a>
```

Have tried the following locators:

```
// driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create")).click();

// driver.findElement(By.name("listbtn")).submit();
//driver.findElement(By.id("listbtn")).click();

//driver.findElement(By.className("btn btn-info")).click();


//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='listbtn']")).click();

//driver.findElement(By.xpath(("td[class='btn btn-info'][value='Create']"))).click();

//driver.findElement(By.linkText("Cancel")).click();
//WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='listbtn']"));
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='listbtn']")).click();
```

But when clicking run, it shows invalid locator -

```
The following is the error exception Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException:
The given selector btn btn-info is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. 
The following error occurred: InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted
Command duration or timeout: 24 milliseconds For documentation on this error, please visit: 
seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
```

Comment: <a href="#"> <button id="listbtn" class="btn btn-info" type="button" name="listbtn">Create</button>  </a>

Comment: Can you update the exception thrown (full stack trace)

Comment: The following is the error exception   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector btn btn-info is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted
Command duration or timeout: 24 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html

Answer (score 3):

I use CSS selectors, thus it would be

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a button[id='listbtn']"));
```

Comment: ok .. will try the above selector

Comment: Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: You can make it a bit less clunky looking if you use id shorthand: "a button#listbtn".  Since ids tend to be unique on a page, chances are you will be able to get away with the css selector "#listbtn" by itself

Comment: @JulianCleary That's true Julian. I write my selectors that way because I like it spelled out - just a personal preference.

Comment: If you prefer a less is more approach see my answer https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/27854/8992

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is because *compound classes are not permitted inside `by.className` locators*.

The `By.id` locator should be the best and the *fastest* option here:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("listbtn"));
```

You can also construct a *CSS selector*:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a button#listbtn"));
```

Note the use of `#` shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the shorter form

```
driver.findElement(By.css("a button#listbtn"));
```